# Finding inverse mod $p^{k}$

Tags: number-theory, inverse

We can find the inverse mod $p$ by taking a primitive root and generating the multiplicative group with it. Is there a similar method for finding the inverse of the invertible elements mod $p^{k}$, $k>1$?

Answer (score 3):

If $p \ne 2$, you can use the same method.  The inverse in *any* cyclic group can be found by the same method.  The invertible elements mod $p^k$ (for $p \ne 2$) form a cyclic group (under multiplication).

Comment: But what is the method of finding a generating element?

Comment: The group has order $m = \varphi(p^k) = (p-1) p^k$.  A random element has probability $\phi(m)/m$ of being a primitive root.  So just choose randomly until one works.

Comment: If you have a primitive root $a$ modulo $p$, it is a well known fact, that $a$ itself or $a+p$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$ for any $k \geq 2$.

Comment: @Robert Probably typo : $\varphi(p^2) = (p-1)p^{k-1}$.

Comment: @BogaertsMarc Thanks for catching the typo.  $m = \varphi(p^k) = (p-1) p^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If prime $p \ne 2$, there is a primitive root mod $p^k$.